# what is the protocol for thank you notes when there are multiple interviewers

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process

I had an interview this morning which lasted several hours.  First I met with several of the IT managers, one of whom I would presumably end up working for if I was hired.  Then an hour with someone from HR.  Then a half hour with the development and data architects, and another hour with several technical staffers.

What is the recommended protocol for thank-you notes in this scenario?  I've read you should respond mainly to the "lead" interviewer (typically the hiring manager) with a courtesy note to HR.  But everyone -- in particular, all of the managers -- asked me questions ... there wasn't a clear "leader", and I'm pretty sure they're all peers.

My guess is I should write a note to each of the technical managers and probably the HR representative as well.  In writing to the technical managers, I should ask them to forward my thanks to their team members.

Comment: I am still waiting for "thank you" notes from those I interviewed and hired, years after the fact - the only time I ever got acknowledged is when they asked me to be their reference for their next job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't hurt to send a thank you to everyone you interview with, whether they have a strong say in the hiring or not.  It is also ok to only send it to the main interviewers involved, but thanks are never a bad thing.  It can be fairly short.  You can add a question if you have one and they're likely to know the answer, or just give a quick thanks for them taking the time and reiterating your interest in the position.

Send it via email: postal mail is not necessary and is also slower.  However, wait at least a couple of hours or even a day before sending it; take time to think about the interview and what you learned about the position.

> Thank you for the opportunity to meet with you and the other engineers
>   today at Acme, Inc.  I like the approach you're taking with
>   just-in-time design and look forward to learning more about widget
>   implementation.
>
> MyName and contact info

Answer (score 8):

Thank you notes are very culture dependent - in 20 years of interviewing on the UK, from both sides of the fence, I've neither sent nor received a thank you note.

Answer (score 1):

You should send thank you letters to only the people who have a deciding vote on whether you will be hired or not.

If you are overambitious, you could consider mailing a letter to everyone you spoke to, but it's not necessary.

Ultimately, it's up to you to decide who you want to mail. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking from the United States, the general rule of thumb is to send thank-yous to anyone with whom you interviewed. With the growth in popularity and usage of email, there is no need to send handwritten letters-- however, you should write an individualized letter to each interviewer.